# Can I export my Facebook friends' contact info to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, facebook, contacts, export, list

Is it possible to export my Facebook friends' contact info to Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

If you a have a Yahoo account you can use that mail to import facebook contact.
Then you can import in your gmail account.

You can follow these simple steps:

**IMPORT CONTATCTS TO YAHOO MAIL ACCOUNT**

1. Login in yahoo mail
2. Click on contacts icon
3. Click on import facebook contact button
4. Insert your facebook credential

The contacts are now imported in yahoo.

**IMPORT CONTACTS IN GMAIL**

Now you can:

**Use the csv file**

1. Export yahoo imported contacts in a .csv file
2. Import the csv file in gmail

Or

**Use the Gmail import function**

1. Login in Gmail
2. Click the Settings gear in your Gmail.
3. Select Settings from the menu that comes up.
4. Go to the Accounts and Import tab.
5. Select what to import
6. Insert your credential to yahoo

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to http://www.friendstogmail.com and download the app.
2. Click the Connect with Facebook button.

Connect with Facebook button on Friends to Gmail and Google+

3. Click Load Friends.

Load Friends button on Friends to Gmail and Google+

4. You’ll get the odd-looking screen below. What it does is prepare the file to be transferred to a Gmail-compatible CSV (comma-separated values) file.

Info prepared for CSV file on Friends to Gmail and Google+
Save the content in any notebook program (e.g., Notepad or TextEdit) to capture the text info.

Copying text from Friends to Gmail and Google+

When you name the file, add the “.csv” suffix.

Saving file as CSV

5. Open Gmail.
6. Click the “Gmail” link at the upper-left corner of the page and select Contacts from the drop-down.
7. Click Import Contacts … in the left navigation pane. The “Import contacts” dialog box will appear.

Import Contacts dialog box in Gmail

8. Browse to the CSV file you just created and click Import.

Gmail will then take the CSV file and import all the pertinent information you extracted from Facebook, including birthdays, city of residence, work details, etc.

9. Check your Google contacts once more to verify the new contacts.

Answer (score -3):

A much easyer way is to use a hosted service like MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](https://nkdagility.com/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth/).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your contacts synced with tons of services including:

- Outlook
- Google Contacts
- Google Calander
- Facebook (One way)
- LinkedIn (One way)
- Windows Live Contacts
- Yahoo Contacts
- Twitter
- Windows Mobile
- Android
- Plaxo
- Soocial
- SheduleWorld
- UNYK
- Vodafone 360 (this is a realy crap service though)
- And tones more

Its also ver cheap and you only need to pay £12 per year if you have more than 50 contacts. I have 2000+ and it work just fine.

Comment: just a heads up. The link to your blog leads to a 403 page.