# Export Contacts from Facebook -- The Painless Methods

Tags: facebook, contacts, export

**Question**
Is there an relatively painless way to export contacts from Facebook?

**Background**
I'm helping my wife get contact info for her network.  I've read the answer to this related question on [getting FB contacts into gMail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/can-i-export-my-facebook-friends-contact-info-to-gmail) but:

- That greasemonkey script is way too complicated for my
  wife
- This guy admits that he barely knew what he was doing when he wrote the tool
- According to his most recent update,
  facebook has changed their site and,
  thereby, broken his script
- I don't care where the data goes, it doesn't have to be gMail, I just need it out of facebook. It could end up in notepad for all I care!

I've read related questions that deal with email info but I mainly need phone numbers.

There must be an easier solution for getting this done.  In fact, my Android phone has a widget that gives access to my facebook phonebook so there MUST be some way to get this data out.  It's so sad that this isn't already built into facebook--their walled garden can be so frustrating.

EDIT:
Bounty added.  If anyone can give me any remotely useful advice on how to pull the phone numbers for my facebook contacts, I'll give full bounty.

Comment: It's possible on your Android device because it was made by Facebook.

Comment: Phone number is not made available via the Facebook API, which is likely why options are limited.

Answer (score 1):

Use Yahoo

1. http://address.yahoo.com/ Sign in to yahoo Address book (create one if you don't have one)
2. At the top you will see some FB icon.  Click that.
3. You'll see another screen with FB/Gmail/etc icons to import.  Click FB
4. Say yes to share your info
5. Done

If it doesn't work, open your Facebook page and choose “Application Settings” under Account. Next remove the “Yahoo! Contact Importer” application from your Facebook profile and try the steps again.

Once in Yahoo, you can export to CSV as well

Comment: This exports *email address and birthday only* no ?

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was whatever was available?  (I could be wrong here)

Comment: Just email addresses

Comment: Yahoo have recently made it so contacts imported from Facebook are not exportable. You have to edit the contact in some way before you can export it. That means touching every single contact.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this need, but have not found a perfect solution yet. Here is my semi-painful solution:

First I registered at [Backupify](https://secure.backupify.com), they generate a backup of my Facebook data once in a while.
And here is what I do when I want to sync from Facebook to my address book:

1. In the Backupify, open the `***_MetaData` file, where *** is your Facebook name.
2. In each line of this file, retrieve facebook id, name, birthday, current location.

I actually wrote a trivial script that filters out the friends whose facebook id is not already in my address book, to produce an HTML list of links to the missing friends' Facebook info pages, from where I can copy-paste.

Getting the phone numbers automatically would probably require screen-scraping, which I don't do.

I have given up on:

- Full automation.
- Synchronization of contacts that I have already in my address book.

But I would be glad if someone came with a better solution.

Comment: Note: Because it does not do scraping, but just provides links to Facebook pages, I believe it does not break Facebook's Terms Of Service.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found.

http://www.waded.org/2009/08/backing-up-contacts-from-facebook/

But it has added cost as per the blogger.

> A warning: Using this technique, as
>   far as I know, will send an email to
>   each contact’s address inviting that
>   person to also use Windows Live. This
>   appears to be its cost. This is not
>   stated clearly by Windows Live, so I’m
>   warning you here, and I’m hoping
>   Windows Live clarifies & provides
>   opt-out option in the future. I still
>   think it’s worth doing.

Comment: Link is dead - that's exactly why answers should be full descriptions instead of links. There is a backup [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100329140110/http://www.waded.org/2009/08/backing-up-contacts-from-facebook/). Don't forget to donate to the Internet Archive, people!

Answer (score 0):

I use a service called MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

A much easyer way is to use a hosted service like MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx).

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your contacts synced with tons of services including:

- Outlook
- Google Contacts
- Google Calander
- Facebook (One way)
- LinkedIn (One way)
- Windows Live Contacts
- Yahoo Contacts
- Twitter
- Windows Mobile
- Android
- Plaxo
- Soocial
- SheduleWorld
- UNYK
- Vodafone 360 (this is a realy crap service though)
- And tones more

Its also ver cheap and you only need to pay £12 per year if you have more than 50 contacts. I have 2000+ and it work just fine.

I did have a couple of hours of De-duping to do afterwords with so many services, but once you have sone that once all is good. Most dups can be deleted, but if you have a contact on Facebook and LinkedIn it is better to merge them.

The problem I have with most sync tool or scripts is that they are one time afairs that leave tonds of duplicates when you re-run them. MemoToo knows which contacts are on multiple services and automaticaly merges them once you tell it that they are the same person.

Answer (score 0):

One method of getting *some* contact data from Facebook is via the Download your information tool on Facebook itself. This only includes **names**, FB-friends-since **dates**, and **emails**.

### How to export:

Adapted instructions from [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/212802592074644/)

#### To download a copy of your Facebook data:

1. Navigate [here](https://www.facebook.com/dyi/) or perform steps 2-5.
2. Click the downward arrow in the top right of Facebook.
3. Select **Settings & privacy**, then click **Settings**.
4. In the left column, click **Your Facebook information**.
5. Next to **Download your information**, click **View**.
6. Click **Deselect all** on the right-hand side of Facebook.
7. Toggle the **Friends** checkbox below it.
8. Select the format of your download request (HTML or JSON) from the middle.
9. Click **Create file** to confirm the download request.

After you've made a download request, it will appear as **pending** in the **Available copies** section of the **Download your information tool**. It may take several hours for them to finish preparing your download request.

Once they are finished preparing your download request, they'll send a notification and email letting you know it's ready.

#### To download a copy of the data that you requested:

1. Go to the **Available copies** section of the **Download your information tool**.
2. Click **Download** and enter your password.

---

For myself, I also edited the HTML file with a regex-compatible find-and-replace tool in a text editor (some will freeze due to everything being on a single line) to remove all the lines with FB-friends-since dates.