# How do you extract friends' birthday and contact information from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, export

I'm tired of Facebook trying to get a hold of all my data and then sharing it with everyone. Can someone tell me a method of getting my friends' birthday and contact information out of Facebook so I can finally quit? I've tried the Yahoo import method but that only exports email addresses. I've also tried all applications like "Birthday exporter" etc and they export nothing (literally, their `.csv` files are empty!).

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3699/export-contacts-from-facebook-the-painless-methods

Answer (score 2):

You can use Greasemonkey to extract your Facebook Phonebook:

1. Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) for Firefox.
2. Follow [these instructions](http://userscripts.org/about/installing) to install the script. The script is on Userscripts at http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/43681.
3. Navigate over to http://m.facebook.com/friends.php? (You’ll have to login).
4. Answer yes to the prompt and sit back – the script will move through your phonebook and eventually dump you a CSV of the results.
5. Copy/Paste the CSV wherever you want.
6. Uninstall the Greasemonkey script.

There is also an application named [FBExport](http://facebookexport.com/) which is claimed to export your all Facebook data.

> Facebook Export uses the Facebook Open
>   Graph protocol to export your Facebook
>   data to an xml file. Facebook Export
>   does not store any data about you. You
>   can then use this xml file to import
>   your data to other services and
>   websites that support the Facebook
>   Export (FBE) format.

Comment: Removed possible malware link. Chrome gave me "The website at shout.setfive.com contains elements from the site three.birkdalehomesforsale.com, which appears to host malware – software that can hurt your computer or otherwise operate without your consent. Just visiting a site that contains malware can infect your computer." when visiting that link. @Mehper: please use a different link instead.

Comment: Strange. I'm using Firefox and haven't received any warning. Anyway, I'm editing my answer to give full instructions.

Comment: @Senseful: No problem :)

Comment: Hey, I tried the GreaseMonkey script, and it didn't show the CSV file, I guess they hard coded the URLs and that's why it's not working. I also tried the other application, but the only information that it allowed me to export was my own. Are any other alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Log-in to Facebook
goto

`Birthdays` > `Export Birthdays` (bottom of the page)

This will give you a URL, copy the URL and either send this to MS Outlook as an ical or use Thunderbird (with Lightning plug-in to display calenders) to create a new calender and give above URL as location.

Note : if you use any other application that supports ical format, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

### Contact information

The "cleanest" way of doing this is by using a Yahoo account because Yahoo has an import mechanism of Facebook contacts (email addresses).

1. Go to the **Contacts** tab of **Yahoo Mail**
2. Click **Import Contacts** button
3. Choose **Facebook**
4. Click **OK** in the pop up from Facebook asking "*Do you want to share your contacts with Yahoo!*"
5. Click **Done** when it gives you the *Congratulations* summary
6. *(now you can either do an export into a file to then import these contacts to your email account/address book, or stop here if you have sync with Yahoo in place; I'll give instructions on creating the extract)*
7. Click on the **Actions** drop-down menu in the main **Contacts** screen and choose **Export All**...
8. Choose the appropriate format of the export from the available options.

### Birthdays

1. Go to the **Birthdays** events page on Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/?sk=bd&ap=1
2. At the bottom of the page choose **Export birthdays**
3. **Copy** the link from the pop up window (this is the link to the online calendar containing birthdays)
4. Use the link to **import/attach** the birthday calendar to your calendar application (like Outlook or Google Calendar)

Comment: I am investigating a way for downloading phone numbers of the friends and will edit the answer/comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Facebook Friend Exporter Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ficlccidpkaiepnnboobcmafnnfoomga) that can [extract your Facebook data](http://www.labnol.org/internet/export-facebook-phone-numbers/18482/)