# How do I export Facebook contacts I have linked to in Hotmail/Outlook web email?

Tags: facebook, outlook.com, contacts, export, outlook

How do I export Facebook contacts I have linked to in Outlook web email?  I can see all my Facebook contacts in the pane to the left, but when I select Manage>Export only the actual Hotmail/Outlook contacts are exported and not the info for my supposedly imported Facebook contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [you can't](http://www.labnol.org/internet/import-facebook-emails-in-outlook/24502/) because according to the subtitle "Outlook is a one-way street" (near the end) *"Outlook will not let you export any data that was auto-imported from a social network network like Facebook, Twitter or LinkedIn. You can see the imported email addresses, phone numbers and birthdays of contacts inside Outlook.com but you can’t take this data out to another service at least yet. If you add any custom data to an auto-imported contact, that data will however be included into the CSV file."*

If you are trying to find a way to export Fb contacts then [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3699/export-contacts-from-facebook-the-painless-methods/4676#4676) and [this article](http://www.labnol.org/internet/export-email-addresses-from-facebook/12970/) (also from the previous author) might help you; they basically tell you to use Yahoo address book to do the trick.  However Yahoo also prevents you from copying Fb addresses and only exports the other email addresses to the *.csv file.
To work around that you may try the following half-baked-solution:

1. Yahoo mail
2. Contacts
3. Actions
4. Print All
5. (.)Your entire Address Book (or just a custom list)
6. (.)Detailed view
7. [Display for Printing]
8. {Copy the resulting output in a text file or spreadsheet and format to fit your needs.}

On the other hand if you *really* need a *.csv file, then you'll need to "Edit details" for each contact to be exported from Yahoo address book (a [dot] "." in the Nickname field will suffice); nevertheless it's a painfully slow solution that I would try to avoid.

Hopefully a better solution will be found in the future.